# signal SIGABRT error in viewController

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue

Hi I am not good at Swift and am getting a signal error. I couldn't find anything that can cause it. I really want to finish this app, can someone help me please.

error-video
https://www.dropbox.com/s/xlvo22fvurivize/error.mov?dl=0

Since I just use option-drag for the segue I am not sure it is related with the code. Should I add something in that class, maybe there is something that I missed ?

```
Could not cast value of type 'recipeApplication.ViewController' (0x1041ff030) to 'recipeApplication.matchesPageViewController' (0x1041ff0d0).
```

This is the error.

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let matchesPage: matchesPageViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! matchesPageViewController

    for var i = 0, a = 0 ; i < data(0).2 ; i++ {

        if data(i).0.isSubsetOf(choosenSet) == true {
            self.myMatchedArray.insert(self.data(i).1, atIndex: a)
            a++
        }
    }

    for var i = 0 ; i < myMatchedArray.count ; i++ {
        //print(myMatchedArray[i])
        matchesPage.dataArray.append(myMatchedArray[i])
    }
}
```

This is the code in my prepareforsegue but like in the video, I have used this one for going another viewController so I did not use it for going back. Like I said I just declared it with a segue ...

Any idea is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Post your relevant code (probably the code in your `prepareForSegue:` method based on the error)

Comment: Also see: https://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1 for info on how to debug crashes

Comment: The error seems to be saying that you're casting something to a `matchesPageViewController` object which isn't one.  It's a `ViewController` instead.

Comment: Try printing segue.destination before the let matchesPage... line. Let me know what it is

Comment: <recipeApplication.ViewController: 0x7f9f1a42b670> it gives this @penatheboss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, when printing `segue.destination`, you received `<recipeApplication.ViewController: 0x7f9f1a42b670>`. That means the destination for your segue was `ViewController`. However, you tried to cast `ViewController` as `matchesPageViewController`. That is why you are getting your error. You should check for this.

```
if let matchesPage = segue.destinationViewController as? matchesPageViewController {
    //Do code
}
```

Hope this helps.